# Attach Registry Property with Edit Control in WiX

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I'm looking to update the value of registry using a Edit Control in WiX installation process.

I have no problem in using Edit Control which I'm using as follows -

```
<Property Id="WIXUI_USERLIST" Value="Demo;" Secure="yes"/>
<Control Id="UsersList" Type="Edit" X="105" Y="192" Width="180" Height="18" Property="WIXUI_USERLIST" Indirect="no" />
```

This works fine to take user input and push the value in registry using WIXUI_USERLIST.

Problem start when I introduce following code to read the registry to display existing value in Edit control in a property and attach it to WIXUI_USERLIST as

```
    <Property Id="USERLIST" Secure="yes">
      <RegistrySearch Id="UserList"
      Root="HKLM"
      Key="[APPLICATIONHIVE]"
      Name="UserList"
      Type="raw"
      Win64="yes" />
    </Property>

<SetProperty Id="WIXUI_USERLIST" Value="[USERLIST]" After="AppSearch">USERLIST</SetProperty>
```

Looking at the log suggest the value correctly passed to the INSTALL phase but gets overwritten by USERLIST.

```
Action 14:37:22: INSTALL. 
Action start 14:37:22: INSTALL.
MSI (s) (78:44) [14:37:22:770]: Running ExecuteSequence
MSI (s) (78:44) [14:37:22:770]: Doing action: FindRelatedProducts
MSI (s) (78:44) [14:37:22:770]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action 14:37:22: FindRelatedProducts. Searching for related applications
Action start 14:37:22: FindRelatedProducts.
MSI (s) (78:44) [14:37:22:772]: Skipping FindRelatedProducts action: already done on client side
Action ended 14:37:22: FindRelatedProducts. Return value 0.
MSI (s) (78:44) [14:37:22:772]: Doing action: AppSearch
MSI (s) (78:44) [14:37:22:772]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action 14:37:22: AppSearch. Searching for installed applications
Action start 14:37:22: AppSearch.
MSI (s) (78:44) [14:37:22:774]: Skipping AppSearch action: already done on client side
Action ended 14:37:22: AppSearch. Return value 0.
MSI (s) (78:44) [14:37:22:774]: Doing action: WIXUI_USERLIST
MSI (s) (78:44) [14:37:22:774]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action 14:37:22: WIXUI_USERLIST. 
Action start 14:37:22: WIXUI_USERLIST
MSI (s) (78:44) [14:37:22:775]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying WIXUI_USERLIST property. Its current value is 'Gurinder;TestUser'. Its new value: 'Gurinder'.
Action ended 14:37:22: SetWIXUI_PORTSERVERADD. Return value 1..
```

In log "Gurinder" is stored in registry and edit during install to "Gurinder;TestUser"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to solve this problem but I believe the following is the probably the most efficient. It just requires a few tweaks to what you've done already.

First, I'd put the default values in `USERLIST` so that `WIXUI_USERLIST` can **always** be set. Second, need the `WIXUI_USERLIST` to be set only once in the UI or Execute sequence. The `SetProperty` element doesn't expose this ability but we can get to it using the `CustomAction` element. Getting the action to run only once in the sequences is the magic.

The resulting code for setting the properties would go a little like this:

```
<Property Id="USERLIST" Value="Demo;" Secure="yes">
  <RegistrySearch Id="UserList"
  Root="HKLM"
  Key="[APPLICATIONHIVE]"
  Name="UserList"
  Type="raw"
  Win64="yes" />
</Property>

<!-- replaces SetProperty but adds the ability to run only in the first sequence -->
<CustomAction Id='SetWIXUI_USERLIST' Property='WIXUI_USERLIST' Value='[USERLIST]'
              Execute='firstSequence'>
<InstallUISequence>
    <Custom Action='SetWIXUI_USERLIST' After='AppSearch' />
</InstallUISequence>
<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action='SetWIXUI_USERLIST' After='AppSearch' />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Update: Additionally, I went and double checked my memory against the MSI SDK. The AppSearch action is only executed once. That means I believe you could probably remove all the `WIXUI_USERLIST` and custom actions and stuff and just use `USERLIST` everywhere. So an even simpler solution is to remove all of this and replace all instances of your `WIXUI_USERLIST` with `USERLIST`. :)